# Plotting regional data in rworldmap

Tags: r, rworldmap

I am using `rworldmap`, and I would like to plot aggregated country data as regions.
I see there are functions called `mapbyregion` and `country2Region`, but if I understand it correctly, the regions are pre-defined, e.g. Stern regions. I would like to use regions of my own choosing? Is this possible? Can it be done with another package?

I have a dataframe with the iso3 codes where I can state with region a country belongs to (and I can edit this to make my own groupings. e.g. EU countries, High Income countries, etc).

Comment: What have you tried? Provide a [example code with data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can start helping you with.

Comment: Well, I've tried     mapbyregion, but if I understand correctly,                  mapByRegion(inFile, nameDataColumn, joinCode, nameJoinColumn, regionType = "", FUN = "mean", na.rm = TRUE, mapTitle = "", lwd = 0.5, ...), the regional options must be one of the following: "GEO3", "GEO3major", "IMAGE24", "GLOCAF", "Stern",
"SRES", "SRESmajor","GBD","AVOIDname, and these aren't my specific regions

Comment: what nya is telling you is that you eddit your question and add the code you tried. Will be easier to help you if we have it.

Comment: I understand that, but it wouldn't help! Because of my question is whether anyone knows of a function or code that can help group by a specific region. I know what I have tried doesn't work, because the mapbyregion function doesn't allow one to self-define regions.

Comment: As @SimonC. says. The information in your comments is exactly the kind of information that belongs in the question. Explain clearly what you have tried, how it does not meet the requirements and then ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

One of these should help.

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)

# example from ?leaflet
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()

# there are two approaches to the custom css problem
#  1.  the easy but less robust way
browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$head(
      # you'll need to be very specific
      tags$style("p{font-size:200%;}")
      # could also use url
      #tags$link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css",rel="stylesheet")
    ),
    m
  ))
)





#  2.  you can add dependencies to your leaflet map
#  this mechanism will smartly handle duplicates
#  but carries a little more overhead
str(m$dependencies)  # should be null to start
# 
m$dependencies <- list(
  htmlDependency(
    name = "font-awesome"
    ,version = "4.3.0"
    # if local file use file instead of href below
    #  with an absolute path
    ,src = c(href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css")
    ,stylesheet = "font-awesome.min.css"
  )
)

m
```